# Dynamic allocation in CUDA - lower contention than handwritten solution?

Tags: scalability, malloc, cuda, contention

Now CUDA allows dynamic allocation on the global memory. However, I couldn't find any reference to the scalability of that `malloc` function: is it any better than, for instance, preallocate a chunk of memory and then just assign the next memory chuck to a thread by atomically incrementing a global integer? This last "home-made" solution works but there is an obvious problem with scalability, so I wonder whether `malloc` takes care of that somehow.

Comment: Wait -- CUDA allows malloc from GPU code now?

Comment: yep, CUDA programming guide 3.2, page 122

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think while your "home-made" solution might be just as good currently, although concurrent calls to a global integer might slow it down, Malloc would be my choice.

This is because it allows for Nvidia to deal with the headache of scalability and to make improvements, in either the hardware or software implementation, that you can taken advantage of just by re-compiling your code at a later date.

Comment: You are right, I'm just cautious about using malloc since it is a well known bottleneck for scalability in multicore programming (so people normally use hoard) - I just wish that there would be a paper/study about the scalability of the CUDA malloc, so I do not need to resort to hand-made solutions.